# VB6 ADODB.Recordset Record.Count doesn't work / EOF & BOF not available

Tags: sql, excel, vb6, adodb, recordset

I've got a question regarding ADODB recordset in VB6, which has confused me for a few weeks. I've written the recordset into worksheets to achieve some results that I can't get from recordset directly.
But as the data set builds up, writing the recordset into worksheet would slow the program down, I wonder if someone could resolve the recordset puzzle for me.

Below is the problem I have - 
1) xRst.Recordcount always returns -1
2) Error message, "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another", pops up on set (A) .cursorlocation to either adUseClient or adUseServer, and (B) .LockType
3) Unable to .getrows on recordset => I believe it's the same cause as xRst.Recordcount returning -1 ?

Below is part of my code. Could above issues caused by limitation of the provider?

```
xConnstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0'; Data Source =" & Thisworkbook.fullname
xCnn.Open xConnstring
xSqlstring = " SELECT * FROM [APRI$] "
Set xRst = xCnn.Execute(xSqlstring)
Msgbox(xRst.RecordCount)
Do Until xRst.EOF
     ......
     xRst.MoveNext
Loop
```

For the recordset, I've also tried two open methods, but doesn't work either.

```
Set xRst.ActiveConnection = xCnn
xRst.Source = xSqlstring
xRst.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
------Error Message Occurs On Below Two Lines------
xRst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
xRst.LockType = adLockOptimistic
xRst.Open
```

Below code will encounter an error, but it will pass through when the two last parameters are removed

```
xRst.Open xSqlstring, xCnn, adOpenKeyset, adUseServer, adLockoptimistic
```

Could someone please kindly advise how I can get the 1) recordset.recordcount, 2) recordset.movenext work?

Thanks heaps in advance.

Comment: IIRC `Recordcount` only works properly with a static cursor. And you can't use a server side cursor with a workbook.

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for the prompt reply. I've tried amend "xRst.Open xSqlstring, xCnn, xadOpenKeyset, adUseServer, adLockoptimistic" to "xRst.Open xSqlstring, xCnn, xadOpenstatic", the recordset still returns -1.

Comment: And when I amend it to "xRst.Open xSqlstring, xCnn, xadOpenStatic, adUseClient, adLockOptimistic", a new error message pops up - "Operation is not allowed when the object is open". But the error message doesn't exists with the last two parameters removed.

Comment: What's the deal with the `x`s ? -1 generally means that you *do* have records - what problem were you having with `getrows`?

Comment: Hi Rory, the "x" is my habit when i declare the variables. The error I get for {getrows} is "Object doesn't support this property or methods"

Comment: You need to post your full code then, I think, since an `ADODB.Recordset` most certainly does support `GetRows`

Comment: Hi Rory, the code runs well with reference library loaded. But the code encounters problems if I declare the varialbe as objects and create them as ADODB.Connect & ADODB.Recordset in the code. Thanks a lot for your help and time xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default cursortype is adOpenForwardOnly. With adOpenForwardOnly or adOpenUnspecified the record count is always returned as -1. Use either adOpenKeySet or adOpenStatic. ie: (I assume sheet name APRI is correct and not APRIL - and there is a worksheet named Dummy to list the results for test):

```
Dim xCnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim xRst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim xConnString As String

xConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0'; Data Source =" & ThisWorkbook.FullName
Set xCnn = New ADODB.Connection
xCnn.Open xConnString
xSqlstring = " SELECT * FROM [APRI$] "
Set xRst = New ADODB.Recordset
xRst.Open xSqlstring, xCnn, adOpenStatic
MsgBox (xRst.RecordCount)
Dim row As Integer
row = 1
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dummy")
Do Until xRst.EOF
    '...
    ws.Cells(row, 1).Value = xRst.Fields(0).Value
    row = row + 1
     xRst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Hi Cetin, the recordcount still returns -1. But the recordset should have 4 records for the test. And xRst.MoveNext command still encounters an error.

Comment: @FoxFeng, I just tested the code with a "table" in it and it correctly returns number of records (92 - Northwind customers) for me. Try with adOpenKeySet. Maybe you changed the code before testing?

Comment: Hi Cetin, thanks a lot for your help. I think I've found what cause the problem. I've declared xCnn & xRst as object, and create them as "ADODB.Connection" and "ADODB.Recordset" during the procedure. The recordset works well once I import the reference library.